# react-hook-form returns register is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

So i'm having an issue with react-hook-form. I have two forms, they are built identically. One is working, another is returning error. I can't find a way to debug it correctly. When i'm commenting out ...register line from Child component, then it's fine. Otherwise i don't know what is happening because the second form i'm having is working without any issues and their wrapping inside div's are the same.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Card from "../../components/Card";
import Form from "../../components/Form/Form";
import Input from "../../components/Form/Input";
import InputCard from "../../components/Form/InputCard";
import InputSelect from "../../components/Form/InputSelect";
import { useNotification } from "../../context/errorContext";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import axios from "axios";

const ClientAdd = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const [isHomeless, setIsHomeless] = useState(false);
  const [personalIdAllowed, setPersonalIdAllowed] = useState(true);

  const defaultOptions = [
    { value: "yes", text: "Jah" },
    { value: "ei", text: "Ei" },
    { value: "refuse", text: "Keeldus" },
  ];

  const defaultPrefilledOptions = [
    { value: "prefilled", text: "Eeltäidetud sihtrühma alusel" },
    { value: "asked", text: "Küsitud osaleja käest" },
  ];

  const { setNotifications, setNotificationVariant, clearNotifications } =
    useNotification();

  const router = useRouter();

  const submitForm = (e, data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit", data);

    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    };

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:80/api/clients",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: headers,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        clearNotifications();
        console.log("Status: ", response.status);
        console.log("Data: ", response.data);
        router.push("/clients/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Something went wrong!", error.response);
        clearNotifications();
        setNotifications(error.response.data.errors);
        setNotificationVariant("danger");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container py-10">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
        <Card>
          <InputCard
            title="Isikuandmed"
            description="Lisa isikuandmed abivajale"
          >
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Eesnimi"
                  id="name"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Perekonnanimi"
                  id="last_name"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Isikukood"
                  id="personal_id"
                  type="number"
                  register={register}
                  required={!personalIdAllowed ? "" : true}
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
                <div className="mt-4">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="allowPersonalId"
                    className="form-checkbox"
                    onChange={() => setPersonalIdAllowed(!personalIdAllowed)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="allowPersonalId">
                    Ei soovi isikukoodi avaldada
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <InputSelect
                  label="Sugu"
                  options={[
                    { value: "m", text: "Mees" },
                    { value: "n", text: "Naine" },
                  ]}
                  id="sex"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              {!personalIdAllowed && (
                <div className="col-span-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Sünnikuupäev"
                    type="date"
                    id="date_of_birth"
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              <div>
                <Input label="Vanus" type="number" disabled />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Telefon"
                  type="tel"
                  id="telephone"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="E-posti aadress"
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <InputSelect
                  label="Kohalik omavalitsus"
                  options={[
                    { value: 0, text: "Hiiu vald" },
                    { value: 1, text: "Saare" },
                    { value: 2, text: "Muu" },
                    { value: 3, text: "Saku vald" },
                  ]}
                  id="local_government"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <InputSelect
                  label="Maakond"
                  options={[
                    { value: 0, text: "Hiiumaa" },
                    { value: 1, text: "Saaremaa" },
                    { value: 2, text: "Pärnumaa" },
                    { value: 3, text: "Saku vald" },
                  ]}
                  id="county"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  className="mr-2 form-checkbox"
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={() => setIsHomeless(!isHomeless)}
                />
                <label>Klient on kodutu</label>
              </div>
              <div></div>
              {isHomeless && (
                <div className="col-span-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Elukoht"
                    id="address"
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              <div>
                <InputSelect
                  label="Kõrgeim omandatud haridustase"
                  options={[
                    { value: 0, text: "Algharidus puudub" },
                    { value: 1, text: "Alg- või põhiharidus" },
                    { value: 2, text: "Üld- või kutseharidus" },
                    { value: 3, text: "Kõrgharidus" },
                  ]}
                  id="education_level"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </InputCard>
        </Card>
        {!personalIdAllowed && (
          <>
            <hr className="py-5" />
            <Card>
              <InputCard title="Ebasoodsas olukorras olevad osalejad">
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – elab koos mittetöötavate leibkonnaliikmetega"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    id="is_living_with_unemployed"
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – elab koos ülalpeetavate laste ja mittetöötavate leibkonnaliikmetega"
                    id="is_living_with_unemployed_and_children"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – elab ülalpeetavate laste ja ühe täiskasvanuga leibkonnas"
                    id="is_living_with_adult_and_children"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – sisserändaja, teise riigi taustaga või rahvusvähemusse kuuluv"
                    id="is_immigrant_or_minority"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – puue määratud"
                    id="is_disabled"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – muu ebasoodne olukord"
                    id="other_unfavorable_condition"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
              </InputCard>
            </Card>
          </>
        )}

        <hr className="py-5" />
        <Card>
          <InputCard title="Tegevustega seotud andmed">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
              <div>
                <Input
                  type="date"
                  label="Tegevuse alustamise kuupäev"
                  id="beginning_of_activities"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  type="date"
                  label="Tegevuse lõpetamise kuupäev, sh katkestamise"
                  id="end_of_activities"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                {/* <Input label="Tegevuse katkestaja" /> */}
                <p>Tegevuse katkestaja</p>
                <div>
                  <InputSelect
                    label="Tegevuses osaleja – muu ebasoodne olukord"
                    id="end_of_activities_initiator"
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    inline
                    register={register}
                    required
                    error={errors}
                    errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                  ></InputSelect>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </InputCard>
        </Card>
        <hr className="py-5" />
        <Card>
          <InputCard title="Õppimine ja osalemine kursustel tegevusega liitumisel">
            <div className="">
              <InputSelect
                label="Õppimine ja osalemine kursustel tegevusega liitumisel"
                id="is_taking_courses_when_joining"
                inline
                options={defaultOptions}
                register={register}
                required
                error={errors}
                errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="">
              <InputSelect
                label="Õppimine ja osalemine kursustel tegevusega liitumisel: eeltäidetud sihtrühma alusel või küsitud"
                id="is_taking_courses_when_joining_prefilled"
                inline
                options={defaultPrefilledOptions}
                register={register}
                required
                error={errors}
                errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
              />
            </div>
          </InputCard>
        </Card>
        <hr className="py-5" />
        <Card>
          <InputCard title="Tööhõive staatus tegevusega liitumisel">
            <div>
              <InputSelect
                label="Tööhõive staatus tegevusega liitumisel"
                id="is_working"
                inline
                options={[
                  { value: null, text: null },
                  { value: "working", text: "Töötav, sh FIE" },
                  {
                    value: "unemployed_short_term",
                    text: "Töötu (kuni 12 kuud)",
                  },
                  {
                    value: "unemployed_long_term",
                    text: "Pikaajaline töötu (üle 12 kuu)",
                  },
                  { value: "not_active", text: "Mitteaktiivne" },
                  { value: "refused", text: "Keeldumine" },
                ]}
                register={register}
                required
                error={errors}
                errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <InputSelect
                label="Tööhõive staatus tegevusega liitumisel: eeltäidetud sihtrühma alusel või küsitud"
                id="is_working_prefilled"
                inline
                options={defaultPrefilledOptions}
                register={register}
                required
                error={errors}
                errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
              />
            </div>
          </InputCard>
        </Card>

        <hr className="py-5" />
        <Card>
          <InputCard title="Kliendi nõusolek ja sobivus">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Kliendi sobivuse põhjendus"
                  id="acceptance_description"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input
                  label="Klient viibib hoolekandeasutuses"
                  id="is_in_care_institution"
                  register={register}
                  required
                  error={errors}
                  errorMessage="Eesnimi on vajalik"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </InputCard>
        </Card>
        <div className="flex justify-center py-5 space-x-4">
          <button className="bg-green-400 py-4 px-6" type="submit">
            Salvesta
          </button>
          <button
            className="bg-red-400 py-4 px-6"
            onClick={() => router.push("/dashboard")}
          >
            Katkesta
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientAdd;
```

Is not working

Child component code:

```
  label,
  id,
  type = "text",
  half = true,
  disabled,
  register,
  required,
  error,
  errorMessage,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label
        htmlFor={id}
        className={`block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ${
          disabled && "opacity-50"
        }`}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type={type}
        name={id}
        id={id}
        autoComplete="given-name"
        disabled={disabled}
        {...register(id, { required, message: errorMessage })}
        className={`mt-1 ${
          error ?? "ring-red-500"
        } focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md ${
          half && "w-1/2"
        }`}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

And error
[image]

There is other form which is built the same and is working perfectly

Comment: I need more information to help... the error is happening in the child component? What is the name of the child component?

Comment: Just a suggestion (something I do often in situations like this): Create a branch and whittle down the code so the problem space is much narrower.  Also, in your running example, try to ensure other warnings are not in the console (I'm not against eslint at all, but I try to ensure my code is very clean because those may have knock-on effects).  In this example there's too many components at play to easily narrow down the problem.

Comment: did you fix this? I'm having similar issues...